# min-width in IE 7 for asp:ListBox

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-7, css

I would like to apply `min-width` for `asp:ListBox` in IE 7. How can I do it? As the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530820.aspx) says, `min-width` is supported in IE 7. But it is not working. Any alternative methods ?

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx. This is a nice post that explains what needs to be done.

Comment: It did not work. See what the documentation says "The remaining limitation here is that it only works on elements which canHaveChildren, so it does not work on childless elements, like form INPUTs or SELECTs."